# how to get the desired output in the second texarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to produce some tables, the idea is that I want to copy this text to my first textarea called:text,

```
33345677 RM  GW
456575 FAC GOG
```

to produce the following output in the second textarea called: out1

```
    "RBD|facebook|W|google|C|33345677~W~RM  GW" "dasd.wbs"
    "RBD|facebook|I|google|C|33345677~E~RM  GW" "dasd.wbs"
    "RBD|facebook|O|google|C|33345677~R~RM  GW" "dasd.wbs"
    "RBD|facebook|W|google|C|456575~W~FAC GOG" "dasd.wbs"
    "RBD|facebook|I|google|C|456575~E~FAC GOG" "dasd.wbs"
    "RBD|facebook|O|google|C|456575~R~FAC GOG" "dasd.wbs"
```

I need to produce 3 tables per row of the first textarea, the rule is that I have two parameters and the fist blank space define the end of the first parameter,
the code for the two textareas is the following:

```
<textarea cols="70" rows="15" id="text" ></textarea>
<div cols="70" rows="15" id="out1" ></div>
```

I would like to produce that tables using one buttom that I built called: Generate Tables,

```
<div class="wrapper">
<button class="button buttom0" style="vertical-align:middle;background-color:Green" onclick="generateTables()"; ><span>Generate Tables</span></button>  
using the function called: generateTables,
function generateTables() {
var newText = document.getElementById("text").value;
document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = newText;
}
```

The problem is that I don´t know how to proceed to display in the second textarea the desired output of above, since I am a beginner in web programming, I use to do it with a template in bash, I really appreciate any suggestion to overcome this situation I wrote the following jsfiddle to be more clear https://jsfiddle.net/ncve6g1d/

I think that maybe is a good idea to define a template to then make replaces as follows:

```
"RBD|facebook|W|google|C|[FIRSTPARAMETER]~W~[SECONDPARAMETER]" "dasd.wbs"
"RBD|facebook|I|google|C|[FIRSTPARAMETER]~E~[SECONDPARAMETER]" "dasd.wbs"
"RBD|facebook|O|google|C|[FIRSTPARAMETER]~R~[SECONDPARAMETER]" "dasd.wbs"
```

Replacing the first parameter and the second one,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a `.replace()` with regular expression for that:

```js
var generate = document.getElementById('generate');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

generate.onclick = function() {
  var text = input.value;
  text = text.replace(/(\S+)\s+(.*)/g, 
         '"RBD|facebook|W|google|C|$1~W~$2" "dasd.wbs"\n' +
         '"RBD|facebook|I|google|C|$1~E~$2" "dasd.wbs"\n' +
         '"RBD|facebook|O|google|C|$1~R~$2" "dasd.wbs"');
  output.textContent = text;
};
```

```html
<textarea id="input" style="width:100%">33345677 RM  GW
456575 FAC GOG</textarea><br>
<button id="generate">Generate table</button><br>
<div id="output" style="width:100%; white-space:pre"></div>
```

Comment: this is really good, I got the desired output, thanks a lot for the approach, let me wait a little to be if there are other approaches.

Comment: Just one more question, I am getting the tables but I am getting three rows instead the six, there is a way to get all the tables with the corresponding linefeeds?

Comment: Did you run the snippet? It produces 6 lines, not 3.

Comment: Yes I ran the snippet in chrome but If I press expand snipped I got less lines,

Comment: This has more to do with the HTML rendering. Add something like `white-space:pre`  style to the output `div` and you will see the line-breaks. Or output it in a `pre` element instead of a `div`. I updated my answer with the first solution.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for the support I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just one more question do you know why, when I copy and paste the tables to a text editor like sublime text  the format is lost, I mean the linefeeds,

Comment: It's because the style `white-space` is ignored by these editors. You can resolve this by using a `pre` tag instead of a `div` tag for your output. If you go for that, you don't need the `style="white-space:pre"`, because that is the default behaviour of `pre`.

Comment: thanks a lot I really appreciate the support, this was really helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123564/discussion-between-neo33-and-trincot).